# Handle input text change event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am writing a jQuery plugin to simulate an editable div.
Here is my code:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.editable = function(){
        return this.each(function(){
            var $this = $(this).hide();
            var div = $('<div>'+$this.val()+'</div>').show().insertAfter($this).data('input',$this);

            $this.data('div',div);

            div.dblclick(function(){
                $(this).hide();
                $(this).data('input').val($(this).text()).show();
            });
            $this.blur(function(){
                $(this).hide();
                $(this).data('div').html($(this).val()).show();                
            });

            $this.change(function(){
                $(this).data('div').html($(this).val());    
            });
        });
    };

})(jQuery);
```

So far, [this works](http://jsfiddle.net/5nZaH/2/) pretty well..

Now, what I want to do, and have no clue how, is to make the div text change if the hidden input value changes.
Means, if I do `$('#editable').val('new text')` the div should change..

I cannot trigger *change* event manually, because the input change will occur within other plugins that I don't control..

Comment: Can you expand on how you expect `$('#editable').val()` to work? Why `val()` as opposed to `html()`? And what element has the id editable?

Comment: As an aside, have you looked into `contenteEditable`? I believe it's pretty thoroughly supported

Comment: You can do this with `jQuery.valHooks` but your plugin design needs to be revised. Look into proper plugin design.

Comment: If other plugins are modifying input fields that they do not "own", then it is their responsibility to do `.trigger('change')`. Perhaps you can contact the plugin owner(s) for this change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this , in your plugin you can extend the val function like this so that change event will trigger when value is changed using the val function.

[How to extend the val method so that the change event is triggered when val is called?](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-extend-a-jquery-method-to-inject-some-custom-functionality/)

Comment: This will instead trigger double `.change()` events for plugins that correctly calls `.change()` after `.val()`. The technique could be combines with a list of inputs, so that (in this case) only `$("#editable").val("new value")` triggers a change. ("Correctly" is depending on purpose of the plugin, I guess.)

Comment: could you please explain more or give me some sample ?

Comment: The $input.change(); is already injected in custom val function, then way you are calling that change again?

Comment: That is the *good* example of a third party plugin. The opposite would be, from the original question, "I cannot trigger change event manually, because the input change will occur within other plugins that I don't control.."

Comment: yes ,this is the good example, but in this fourm the plugin wont call the 'change' right ?

Answer (score 2):

When you double click the `<div>` to edit the `<input>`, you are overwriting the value of the input with this line:

```js
$(this).data('input').val($(this).text()).show();
```

If the `.change()` event hasn't been triggered (as you indicate), it means you are overwriting the changes made by the external plugin with the "old" content of your div. Remove `.val()` to avoid that problem.

```js
$(this).data('input').show();
```

As an alternative to relying on the external plugin triggering `.change()`, you can check the value by polling. While this is not recommended if events are available, it will not have a huge impact if you set the polling interval reasonably. Since you are dealing with humans entering data in a form, I'm guessing you don't need to poll more often than every 250 milliseconds.

See [`$("#editable").changePolling();`](https://gist.github.com/2944926) for a wrapper that checks the current value and triggers `.change()` if it has changed. See [the forked jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joelpurra/v8YVQ/) for an example based on your code.

Comment: @sonia: are you testing in IE? IE (and possibly other browsers) are picky about including scripts that are not served with the right content type. I'v

Comment: @sonia: The right content type would be [`application/javascript` or `text/javascript`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript). I've [linked the script raw from my gist](https://gist.github.com/raw/2944926/d87c96c1529d7f5e8c8c4015c7b9100a5f6a8db8/changepolling.joelpurra.js) which doesn't serve the right content type. For testing purposes you can copy-paste the entire `.changePolling()` source code into the jsFiddle, and then run it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to make your jQuery plugin support methods as described on [Plugins/Authoring - Namespacing](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Namespacing):

Then you will have something like this:

```
(function( $ ){

  var methods = {

    init : function( options ) { 
      return this.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this).hide();
        var div = $('<div>'+$this.val()+'</div>').show().insertAfter($this).data('input',$this);

        $this.data('div',div);

        div.dblclick(function(){
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).data('input').val($(this).text()).show();
        });
        $this.blur(function(){
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).data('div').html($(this).val()).show();                
        });
    },

    value : function( str ) {
      return this.each(function(){
        $(this).val(str);
        $(this).data('div').html($(this).val());
      });
    }
  };

  $.fn.editable = function( method ) {

    // Method calling logic
    if ( methods[method] ) {
      return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
      return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
      $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.editable' );
    }    

  };

})( jQuery );
```

Then you will use it like this:

```
$('#editable').editable('new value that will sync the related div');
// instead of `$('#editable').value('...')`
```

I strongly recommend you to read the [Plugins/Authoring - Namespacing](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Namespacing)'s article on jQuery.

---

**UPDATE** Since I made a mistake understanding the question, I came with the following proposed solutions. It is not the best way to do it.

**I strongly recommend you to review your plugin design, because it is not accessible in my personal opinion.**

But, since I cannot see the whole scenario, the following piece of code will do the trick

```
(function() {

    // Store the original jQuery.val()
    var $$val = $.fn.val;

    // Add a hook.
    $.fn.val = function(s) {

      // Call your plugin change event.
      $(this).editable('change');

      // Delegate to the original jQuery.val function.
      return $$val.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
    };

  // Your plugin stuff...
})
```

HTH

Comment: I can add `.trigger('change')` isn't easier? but inputs will be used by other plugins as said, so it will be only `.val('new text')`

Comment: For the sake of the negative points, I will try to light my proposed answer with a JSFiddle with your described behavior. I have already written my jQuery Editable plugin and I have already faced this _common_ situation, I pretty sure this way of doing will do what you wan to.

Comment: @kiros, I read the whole question before answering. Did you test or at least test my answer?

Comment: The asker clearly said **the input change will occur within other plugin that I don't control**

Comment: You are right @kiros my proposed answer will not works in this case.